# Составить регулярное выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

[image: описание задания]

Мне попалось задание на регулярки. Я разбил его на две подзадачи: 1)составить первое слово с двумя подряд идущими гласными 2) составить второе слово в котором не больше 3 согласных.

В итоге соединив их хочу получить нужное выражение.

Столкнулся с тем что я не могу понять как составить второе слово. Вот выражение, до которого додумался сам(почти полностью уверен что первое слово я записал правильно), оно конечно нерабочее, но буду рад если поможете исправить вторую часть так, чтобы всё работало.

`\b\w*[аеёиоуыэюя]{2}\w*\s+\w*[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ]{0,3}\b`

P.s. пишу на питоне с использованием библиотеки re

Comment: Ноль согласных это тоже "не больше трёх".

Answer (score 2):

Наверняка можно сделать лучше, но пока так. Громоздко, но выдает правильный результат на тестовых данных.
Первая часть такая же, а вторая - негативный просмотр вперед (НПВ) на предмет 4+ согласных в следующем слове. В конце НПВ - подвыражение `|\s*$`, которое не дает сработать захвату, если слово с двумя гласными подряд последнее в строке.

```
\b\w*[аеёиоуыэюя]{2}\w*(?!\s+\b(?:[аеёиоуыэюя]*[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ][аеёиоуыэюя]*){4,}|\s*$)\b
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/6BxIUN/1)

Comment: Сократил Ваше регулярное выражение, убрав лишние последовательности. Не против, если Вы укажете его как свой ответ. https://regex101.com/r/6BxIUN/2

Comment: @ReinRaus в вашем примере захватывается последнее слово "синеет", после которого нет слова, это вроде бы не по условию

Comment: Если требуется такое условие, то проще сделать указанную проверку так: https://regex101.com/r/6BxIUN/3

Comment: @АлексейР Благодарю покорнейше за решение. Не могли бы вы объсянить принцип работы НПВ? Почему у нас несколько раз указаны гласные и вообще в целом не совсем понятно что происходит после ?:

Comment: В НПВ (после `(?!`) указано подвыражение, содержащее 4+ согласных буквы, которого не должно быть в строке, чтобы условие захвата стало истинным. `(?:` - это начало незахватываемой группы, которое используется для группировки с целью применения квантификатора `{4,}` к подвыражению `[аеёиоуыэюя]*[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ][аеёиоуыэюя]*`, которое представляет собой последовательность гласных и согласных. При этом согласные могут быть окружены гласными, а могут и не быть окружены, поэтому к гласным применен квантификатор `*`.

Comment: *несколько раз указаны гласные* - это да, вроде бы одно вхождение гласных избыточно, как подсказывает @ReinRaus. Учитывая цикличность подвыражения `(?:[аеёиоуыэюя]*[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщ][аеёиоуыэюя]*){4,}`, от последней группы гласных можно отказаться

Comment: @АлексейР Спасибо вам!